# org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException using maven

Tags: unit-testing, maven, testing, junit, pom.xml

I am facing the following error while I am trying to test my application using junit.

```
 org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
            at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.tryGetMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:57)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isSuiteOnly(JUnit3TestChecker.java:64)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.isValidJUnit3Test(JUnit3TestChecker.java:59)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit3.JUnit3TestChecker.accept(JUnit3TestChecker.java:54)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.common.junit4.JUnit4TestChecker.accept(JUnit4TestChecker.java:51)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultDirectoryScanner.locateTestClasses(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:84)
            at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:186)
```

The pom.xml looks like this :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sample</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Java.Net</id>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <plugins>
        <!-- Maven War file generator plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            <include>**/*.css</include>
                            <include>**/*.html</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Maven compiler plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
            <classpathDependencyExcludes>
            <!-- exclude code absent api -->
            <classpathDependencyExclude>javax.faces:javax.faces-api</classpathDependencyExclude>
            </classpathDependencyExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have tried adding the javaee plugin as mentioned as a solution on stackoverflow also I have tried adding the surefire plugin but none worked. Can you please tell me what the problem could be as it is saying that the target is null.

Comment: First a plugin should not defined as a dependency only in the plugin are not in the dependencies are furthermore you've defined two different versions of the maven-surefire-plugin (2.12, 2.14.1).

Comment: I have removed the 2.12 plugin but that didn't work still. I couldn't understand the 1st point you mentioned in your comment

Comment: You have defined the maven-surefire-plugin as dependency after the mockito-all dep. This should be removed.

Comment: Even after removing it.. I am getting the same exception..

Comment: The problem is within this error message: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/servlet/ServletException`. How do you start the unit tests? Apart from that remote the repository definition you have in your pom.xml file (Java.Net).

Comment: do you mean in the command prompt? If yes, then I use "mvn test" command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31934/discussion-between-mitaksh-gupta-and-khmarbaise)